# Workaround Google Sheets API does not accept range request without specifying desired final line

Tags: google-sheets-api

My spreadsheet has values in this model:

[image]

And I need to create a list to use in Python, including the empty fields that exist between values:

```
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
    API_NAME = 'sheets'
    API_VERSION = 'v4'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
    spreadsheet_id = sheet_id
    get_page_id = 'Winning_Margin'
    range_score = 'O1:O10000'

    spreadsheets_match_score = []
    range_names2 = get_page_id + '!' + range_score
    result2 = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
                spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_names2, valueRenderOption='UNFORMATTED_VALUE').execute()
    sheet_output_data2 = result2["values"]
    for i, eventao2 in enumerate(sheet_output_data2):
        try:
            spreadsheets_match_score.append(sheet_output_data2[i][0])
        except:
            spreadsheets_match_score.append('')
```

In this case, this list (`spreadsheets_match_score = []`) would result in:

```
["0-0","0-0","4-0","0-1","6-0","","","","0-3","2-2","","","","","0-1","","","3-0","1-1","3-1","","","",""]
```

My spreadsheet currently has 24 rows, but it will grow without a fixed ending value.

So, I tried to use the range without putting the value of the last line (`range_score = 'O1:O'`), but it doesn't accept, the range needs to specify the final line (`range_score = 'O1:O10000'`).

I put `10000` exactly so I don't have to change, but this is very wrong to do, because it does a search for a non-existent range, I'm very afraid that in the future it will generate an error.

Is there any method so that I can not need to specify the last row of the worksheet?
To be something like:

```
range_score = 'O1:O'
```

Comment: About `My spreadsheet currently has 24 rows, but it will grow without a fixed ending value.`, if the last row is 24, when `O1:O10000` is used as the range, 24 rows including empty rows are retrieved. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, in your script, what is `append` method? Is this related to your question?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike , about the number of rows, I just wanted to say that currently the spreadsheet has ```24``` rows but new values are added every day, so there will come a time when there will be more than ```10,000``` rows, so I was wondering how to make it not run the risk of collecting less data in the future than exists.

Comment: And about ```append```, it's just a method that it analyzes the data, if the line is blank, it gives an error when trying to create the list, so when I put it to when it finds a blank value, then append a ```''``` blank value in the list.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I thought that if you want to retrieve the column "O", `'Winning_Margin'!O1:O` can be used. How about this? And, unfortunately, I cannot understand `And about append, it's just a method that it analyzes the data, if the line is blank, it gives an error when trying to create the list, so when I put it to when it finds a blank value, then append a '' blank value in the list.`.

Comment: @Tanaike I find it very strange to have to put a huge value to never have the chance to collect less data, for example, putting something like ```O1:O10000000000000000000```, it looks very ugly and seems unreliable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I find it very strange to have to put a huge value to never have the chance to collect less data, for example, putting something like O1:O10000000000000000000, it looks very ugly and seems unreliable.`. Because when `O1:O` is used, the values to the last row can be retrieved. So, first, I asked about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: @Tanaike I found the problem, it was not able to fetch values when row ```1``` was empty, generating an error. Thank you very much, it really works ```O1:O```!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the range specification method for data collection, can use either `range_score = 'O1:O'` or `range_score = 'O1:O100000000000'` if looking for all the column rows.

In the case of the question, the problem was when line `1` of the desired column has no values, being null, the request failed but because of the empty `["values"]` return.

In short, I was looking for the error in the wrong place.